# How to backup a bulletin board hosted by a 3rd party?

Tags: backup, screen-scraping

A friend has asked me to back up this forum:

http://oldforums.comicbookresources.com/

It's powered by vBulletin.

Something bad had happened there and the hosts no longer want to host, and are unresponsive. It is going to go dark any moment now. They are important to my friend.

These forums being fairly standard software, is there a screen-scraping utility allowing to backup everything?

Comment: The website is already dark.  The administrative control panel would have offered a mechanic to download the database.  The forum files itself would have been entirely different situation. that would have required FTP access.

Comment: It's not as good as a database backup, but you might be able to get the content with a program like [HTtrack](http://www.httrack.com/).